How can we create a customized table of contents (ToC) of incomplete chapters in a large document?
I am writing a large document containing many chapters, sections and subsections. Some of the chapters/sections are not yet complete. In order to remind me of incomplete sections, I want to create a two tables of contents (ToC) - one containing ToC the list of all sections/chapters (this I have achieved) and another customized ToC containing the list of only the titles of the incomplete sections/chapters etc.
How can I achieve this?

There are no suitable information about the used class, relevant packages etc. in your question. So I guess using the famous KOMA-Script, which would allow the following:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}% Just for dummy content.
%\usepackage{hyperref}% would also work, but wasn't aked
\DeclareNewTOC[listname={Incomplete Contents}]{mtoc}
\newif\ifincomplete

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\addtocentrydefault}{%
  \ifincomplete
    \tocbasic@addxcontentsline{mtoc}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \global\incompletefalse
  \fi
}
{\typeout{Extension of \string\addtocentrydefault\string done.}}
{\typeout{Extension of \string\addtocentrydefault\string failed!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftoc{mtoc}
\blinddocument
\incompletetrue
\chapter{Example of incomplete chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Complete section}
\lipsum[2]
\incompletetrue
\section{Example of incomplete section}
\lipsum[2]
\incompletetrue
\section{Example of one more incomplete section}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One more complete section}
\end{document}

Here are the two contents pages:

However, if you use another class, like the standard classes, you can load package tocbasic and patch \addcontentsline instead of \tocbasic@addxcontentsline:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mwe}% Just for dummy content.

\usepackage{tocbasic}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% would also work, but wasn't aked
\DeclareNewTOC[listname={Incomplete Contents}]{mtoc}
\newif\ifincomplete

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\addcontentsline}{%
  \ifincomplete
    \Ifstr{#1}{toc}{%
      \addcontentsline{mtoc}{#2}{#3}%
      \global\incompletefalse
    }{}
  \fi
}
{\typeout{Extension of \string\addtocentrydefault\string done.}}
{\typeout{Extension of \string\addtocentrydefault\string failed!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftoc{mtoc}
\blinddocument
\incompletetrue
\chapter{Example of incomplete chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Complete section}
\lipsum[2]
\incompletetrue
\section{Example of incomplete section}
\lipsum[2]
\incompletetrue
\section{Example of one more incomplete section}
\lipsum[3]
\section{One more complete section}
\end{document}


For more information about \DeclareNewTOC and about how to configure TOC entries using package tocbasic see the KOMA-Script manuals.

Nice demo of using tocbasic, but will not mesh well with hyperref.

@yannisl If you have a problem using hyperref ask a question about it. The question here does not mention hyperref at all. However, if I add \usepackage{hyperref} to one of the examples, I don't see any problem. Usually all KOMA-Script classes and packages work with hyperref.
